# what is wrong with my loop - looping through views

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Could someone point out what is wrong with my for loop? I'm trying to loop thru UIImageViews to make all hidden. All the subviews are UIImageViews. Thanks in advance.

```
int i;
int num = [[self myView]subviews];
for (i=0; i<num; i++) 
{
  UIImageView *currentView = [self.tabber.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
  currentView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: I think your code didn't make it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[self myView] subviews]` refers to the list of subviews, not the number of them. What you want is

```
for(i = 0; i < [[[self myView] subviews] count]; i++)
```

Comment: The compiler will have given a warning ("Initialization makes integer from pointer") about the offending line. Don't ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 5):

Ian, Martin and Aram pointed out the error in your code.

I want to point out another way of iterating through an array: [Fast Enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html)

```
for (UIView *view in [self.myView subviews])
{
    view.hidden = YES;
}
```

It has several advantages over C-style counting variable based iterating, such as

- cleaner code — no counter variable needed.
- Enumeration is “safe”—the enumerator has a mutation guard so that if you attempt to modify the collection during enumeration, an exception is raised.

Answer (score 0):

`[[self myView]subviews];` returns a `NSArray` of views, not an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

A UIView's subview property returns an NSArray.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html